# Grammar/vocab to introduce a better alternative (sounds like 차다리 or 자다리)

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

There is a grammar/word in Korean to introduce (and emphasize) a better alternative. It sounds like "차다리" or "자다리." What am I thinking of? I hear it often in conversation, but am having trouble finding an explanation for this grammar or word.

You could use it to start the translation of a sentence like this: "It would be better to rest (instead of making the injury worse)."

Answer (score 3):

Found it: "차라리"

It's very similar to 오히려, but I think 오히려 is more neutral in terms of nuance.

Comment: It's actually spelled 차라리

Comment: @gaeguri: Good catch!

Answer (score 3):

*** 오히려**

> (1) 일반적인 기준이나 예상, 짐작, 기대와는 전혀 **반대**가 되거나 다르게
>
> be different or oppose to general standard, estimation, or
>   expectation = 도리어

여름에는 살이 빠지지만 나는 도리어 더 찐다

In summer, we are going to be slim, but I am fat

경제는 성장했지만 도리어 빛은 더 많아 졌다.

Our economic grows largely, but debt is more.

별로 대단한 일도 아닌데 칭찬해 주시니 오히려 부끄럽습니다.

Even though it is trivial thing, I am shamed because you encourage
me.

어두웠지만 거리의 전등불로 오히려 환했다

In the evening, it was bright because of streetlight.

> (2) 앞의 내용보다 뒤의 내용이 더 나을때
>
> Second opinion is better than first opinion

싸울바에는 오히려 헤어지는게 좋다

Separation is better than fighting

*** 차라리**

> '차라리'는 여러 가지 사실을 말할 때에, '저리 하는 것보다 이리 하는
>   것이 나음'을 이르는 말.
>
> When we enumerate **several ways in some situation**, we compare them

온실속의 꽃처럼 사느니 차라리 비바람에 시달리는 풀처럼 살겠다

I will live like a grass in field rather than live like a flower

방과후에, 빈둥거리는 것보다 차라리 청소하는 것이 좋다.

After school, cleaning is better than playing.

@@ In fact, bacause we use 만, even though we miss 오히려, 도리어, or 차라리, meaning of sentence is not changed.